# Scrapy: How do I select the first a tag inside a div element using XPath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using Scrapy's SitemapSpider to pull all product links from their respective collections.  My list of sites are all Shopify stores and and the code that links to the products look like this:

```html
<div class="grid__item grid-product medium--one-half large--one-third">
  <div class="grid-product__wrapper">
    <div class="grid-product__image-wrapper">
      <a class="grid-product__image-link" href="/collections/accessories/products/black-double-layer-braided-leather-bracelet">
        <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1150/5108/products/product-image_50ce19b1-c700-4a77-9638-e2ac66a3acef_grande.jpg?v=1457310318" alt="Black Double Layer Braided Leather Bracelet" class="grid-product__image">
          </a>
      
    </div>

    <a href="/collections/accessories/products/black-double-layer-braided-leather-bracelet" class="grid-product__meta">
      <span class="grid-product__title">Black Double Layer Braided Leather Bracelet</span>
      <span class="grid-product__price-wrap">
        <span class="long-dash">—</span>
        <span class="grid-product__price">
          
            $ 15
          
        </span>
      </span>
      
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, both href's are the exact same. The problem I'm having is scraping both links when using the following code:

```
product_links = response.xpath('//div//a[contains(@href, "collections") and contains(@href, "products")][1]/@href').extract()
```

I'm trying to select the div element that has both a tags as descendants.  From that, I only want to pull the href from the first a tag to avoid duplicate links.

Although each site is a Shopify, their source code for the collections page isn't the exact same.  So the depth of the a tag under the div element is inconsistent and I'm not able to add a predicate like

```
//div[@class="grid__item grid-product medium--one-half large--one-third"]
```

Comment: I've made a completely new post that clarifies what I'm asking and gives code that's much more simplified.  I'd rather not delete this question in case anyone else has a similar problem.  [Link to improved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258500/xpath-and-scrapy-scraping-links-when-the-depth-and-quantity-of-a-tags-are-inco)

Answer (score 0):

```
product_links = response.xpath('//div//a[contains(@href, "collections") and contains(@href, "products")][1]/@href').extract()
print(product_links[0])  # This is your first a Tag
```

Comment: This won't work.  When using Scrapy's SitemapSpider, response.xpath() will return a list for each page it scrapes from the sitemap. 
 print(product_links[0]) returns the first item of each list, so I'll only be scraping the first product from each collection

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `extract_first()` command to  to extract only the first matched element. And benifit of using this is that it avoids an `IndexError` and returns `None` when it doesn’t find any element matching the selection.

So, it should be :

```
>>> response.xpath('//div//a[contains(@href, "collections") and contains(@href, "products")]/@href').extract_first()
u'/collections/accessories/products/black-double-layer-braided-leather-bracelet'
```